# Find positon of words in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list which looks like this:

```
listWords = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Then I would like to use enumerate over the list, to get the word positions, but the output should look like this:

```
foo [0,3]
bar [1,4]
foobar [2]
```

I was thinking of using a set since it will take the unique values and then enumerate with a counter of the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary, and add indices to lists for the values:

```
indices_per_word = {}
for index, word in enumerate(listWords):
    indices_per_word.setdefault(word, []).append(index)
```

For your sample, this produces:

```
>>> listWords = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> indices_per_word = {}
>>> for index, word in enumerate(listWords):
...     indices_per_word.setdefault(word, []).append(index)
... 
>>> indices_per_word
{'bar': [1, 4], 'foo': [0, 3], 'foobar': [2]}
>>> for word, indices in indices_per_word.items():
...     print(word, indices)
... 
bar [1, 4]
foo [0, 3]
foobar [2]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. What if I would use a dict instead of a list?

`dictWords = {'123':['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'bar'],'456'['foo1', 'bar1', 'foobar1', 'foo1', 'bar1']} `

Comment: @klabanus: and what would the output be?

Comment: Output should be the same, but every value of the keys should be treated as it's own list. Output:
`bar [1, 4]
foo [0, 3]
foobar [2]`
`bar1 [1, 4]
foo1 [0, 3]
foobar1 [2]`

Comment: Something like: `r = [[i for i in listWords[x]] for x in listWords.keys()]`
 `for i in range(len(r)): ## do something `

Comment: @klabanus: just loop over the values separately; `for value in dictionary.values(): for index, word in enumerate(value): ...`.

Comment: Ok nearly there. what i meant was: `bar [1, 4] foo [0, 3] foobar [2]` START 'COUNTING' AGAIN `bar1 [1, 4] foo1 [0, 3] foobar1 [2]` If i now have a 'bar' in the second list it will merge that position into 'bar' occurrence of first list

Comment: @klabanus: yes, the double loop I gave you starts counting again; a new `enumerate()` call on each separate list.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work: `for value in listWords1.values(): 
 for index, word in enumerate(value):
     indices_per_word.setdefault(word, []).append(index)

for word, indices in indices_per_word.items():
 print(word, indices)`

If 'bar' occurs in both lists on the same position, it will print for example 'bar [2,2]', i want it to print 'bar [2]' for the first list and then if it approaches the second list again 'bar [2]'.

Comment: @klabanus: then treat the two entirely separate. Move `indices_per_word = {}` and printing into the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

One could do it with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict), like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

indices_per_word = defaultdict(list)
for index, word in enumerate(listWords):
    indices_per_word[word].append(index)

indices_per_word

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'foobar': [2], 'foo': [0, 3], 'bar': [1, 4]})
```